# Apache works with domain, but not subdomain

Tags: web-server, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I can set up a proxy like so

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.ca

   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyVia Full
   #ProxyRequests off
   # setup the proxy
   <Proxy *>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>
   ProxyPass        / http://10.0.0.0:123/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.0.0:123/
</VirtualHost>
```

But not when I include subdomains like so

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName dev.example.ca

   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyVia Full
   #ProxyRequests off
   # setup the proxy
   <Proxy *>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>
   ProxyPass        / http://10.0.0.0:123/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.0.0:123/
   ErrorLog logs/vhost-error_log
   CustomLog logs/vhost-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I have looked all over the net, and the above solution should be working, but it is not. Any ideas what is wrong.

**EDIT** As per [JoeT's](https://serverfault.com/users/134370/user16081-joet) requests, I have updated the above code to include logs, which are shown below (vhost_error_log was empty)

vhost-access_log

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [26/Aug/2015:18:09:58 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4607
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [26/Aug/2015:18:09:58 -0700] "GET /assets/application-ffeeed35892b38ff9bfa135564fb0830.css HTTP/1.1" 304 256
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [26/Aug/2015:18:09:58 -0700] "GET /assets/print-47fe51cdf70398e5e54b544e0f5cc718.css HTTP/1.1" 304 255
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [26/Aug/2015:18:09:58 -0700] "GET /assets/application-3302fd299e1a3e701974f594a4a76c56.js HTTP/1.1" 304 257
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [26/Aug/2015:18:09:58 -0700] "GET /assets/logo-ca207549507c811d027110077cf86e90.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 255
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [26/Aug/2015:18:09:58 -0700] "GET /assets/icon-search-1aee2102ac9ef7c077acce219d346074.png HTTP/1.1" 304 254
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [26/Aug/2015:18:09:58 -0700] "GET /assets/jquery-ui/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100-d20cf782ea2d212335fa15f2ecb5e412.png HTTP/1.1" 304 254
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [26/Aug/2015:18:09:58 -0700] "GET /?limit=20&offset=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 3394
```

Comment: what are the symptoms?  Check your error apache logs, add some logging in your VirtualHost block,`ErrorLog logs/vhost-error_log
    CustomLog logs/vhost-access_log common`

Comment: @user16081-JoeT I included the information you requested

Comment: what happens when you try?  does apache fail to run, or is there an error?

Comment: @user16081-JoeT I have vhosts for both example.ca and dev.example.ca. example.ca works in the browser, but dev.example.ca just gives me the standard browser "can't find url"

Comment: maybe a dumb question but if you `ping dev.example.ca` u get the same result as `ping example.ca`?  what does your '/etc/hosts' file look like?

Comment: @user16081-JoeT difficult to answer. We are behind a sonicwall firewall which disables ping. For the same reason, I don't think `/etc/hosts` would be applicable here

Comment: i meant ping as a test for what ip address your system looks to for 'dev.example.ca' vs 'example.ca'. Even if you get no ping response, it should still resolve an ip address. This firewall setup could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the solution not through the apache server, but through my domain provider.

You have to login to your account and create the subdomains, ie

- john.example.com
- jane.example.com
- francis.rutherford.jr.the.third.example.com

I had previously only set up a local apache server, and my `/etc/hosts` file was catching the request to `example.ca` and `john.example.ca`, and automagically redirecting it to 192.0.0.123